# What means ';' inside of for statement?

Tags: java, syntax, insertion-sort

I'm trying to understand the follow code below:

```
/**
   * Simple insertion sort.
   * @param a an array of Comparable items.
   */
  public static void insertionSort( Comparable [ ] a )
  {
      for( int p = 1; p < a.length; p++ )
      {
          Comparable tmp = a[ p ];
          int j = p;
          for( ; j > 0 && tmp.compareTo( a[j-1] ) < 0; j-- )
              a[ j ] = a[ j - 1 ];
          a[ j ] = tmp;
      }
  }
```

But i'm not sure what means `for( ; )`  so I need your help guys.
Sorry if it's duplicated but I search here and in Google but nothing so far.

Comment: This is simply intializing the variable j, as you must know all loop have three part initialization, condition check , increment/decrement

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first part of a for loop is what happens before the looping begins. Usually it's used for assigning a variable.

The ";" with nothing (apart from the bracket) before it merely says "There's nothing I want doing before the start of the loop". No variable needs to be assigned, etc.

Comment: All 3 parts of the for loop are optional.  Thus, for example, you can use `for(;;)` for an infinite loop.  Though I'd usually prefer using the equivalent `while (true)` instead.

Comment: Very true. for(;;) is only preferable when testing and you might want to add in variables, etc. while(true) is definitely more readable.

Comment: I was going to say you should change it to `for(int j)...`, but then realized he referenced `j` under the loop.  This means, however, that he could not remove the line above the for loop completely and would instead need `int j;for(j = p...` .  So, I rolled back to your version, even though it's still a bit wrong.

Comment: Hmm, now I get it. Thank you all, very useful, but I prefer while declaration instead tough, understading what is the meaning.

Comment: @Brian: Oops - I must admit, I very quickly put that in and I'm also not a Java programmer ;)

Comment: @Muu: My point was to tell you that your code is still wrong, so you should probably edit your post.  You cannot remove the line above the loop as you suggest as the code will not compile.  You would need to instead replace `int j = p;` with `int j;`.  You cannot remove it completely and use `for (int j = p...` because then `j` would be out of scope in the line `a[ j ] = tmp;`.

Answer (score 2):

It is simple: It basically means

```
for(..a.. ; ..bb.. ; ..c..){ // }.
```

..a.. : is what you initialize if any or leave it empty.
..b.. : Any check you want to carry once a loop is run once.
..c.. Any change to the variable after the loop is run once

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're wandering about the second for loop syntax. It's just a regular for loop without any initialization part. `j` must be declared before the loop because it's used outside, after the loop has ended.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a separator.
If there's nothing in front of it, that means that part of the logic is empty.
The format is

```
for(  <stuff to do before starting the loop>
    ;
      <stuff to do before each iteration, and maybe give a value of 0 to terminate it>
    ;
      <stuff to do at the end of each iteration>
   )
```

Frankly I find it very flexible, because not every loop is of the form "do this for each xxx".
What you put in each of those sections is really arbitrary.